# MBaaS Push Service returning FPWSE0004E Invalid JSON despite valid input

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm attempting to POST a Push message to the Bluemix MBaaS Endpoint through the Console in the [API Documentation](https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api/#!/push). App id and secret are both set, the message is from the sample under Model Schema with device id added. My local `jsonlint` install calls this valid JSON and yet I get HTTP Response Code 400:

```
{
  "message": "Bad Request - Invalid JSON",
  "docUrl": "http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#troubleshoot/index-gentopic3.html",
  "code": "FPWSE0004E"
}
```

Push is listed as being 'Up' on the [Status Page](http://estado.ng.bluemix.net/). Any hints?

Attempted message (device id redacted):

```
{
  "message": {
    "alert": "ABCD",
    "url": ""
  },
  "target": {
    "deviceIds": [
      "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "tagNames": [
      ""
    ],
    "consumerIds": [
      {
        "consumerId": "",
        "alias": [
          ""
        ],
        "platforms": [
          ""
        ]
      }
    ],
    "platforms": [
      ""
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "gcm": {
      "payload": " JSON object"
    },
    "apns": {
      "payload": "JSON object",
      "badge": 0,
      "sound": "",
      "category": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you do have valid JSON formatting you may not have a valid JSON block for what the backend is expecting. In regards to the model schema you are using above, they have included all of the optional values to show the correct formatting. You should only include the parameters to which you want to use or else it may cause issues. For example using MBaaS push you are only allowed to send to one target such as tags, devices, consumers, or platforms. Can you attempt to send the a push using a basic JSON body such as:

```
{
     "message": {
       "alert": "testing",
         "url": ""
       },
      "target":{
        "deviceIds":[
       "ENTER_VALID_DEVICE_ID_HERE"
]
      }
}
```

I was able to send a Push notification using the API Documentation (Swagger doc) with the above body after setting a valid appID and appSecret.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction! May I suggest an update to the documentation? As it is now, the (erroneous) payload snippet I used above can be set as a sample payload within the Swagger doc with a simple "Click to set as parameter value". For me at least, this implied it is considered a valid payload with some blanks to fill out. The documentation also does not point out that the target selectors are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @asmodeus we have reached out to the team that owns this content to see how we can improve it. I am glad it is working for you now though